# What is the best way to extract component information that is intersected with raycaster?

Tags: aframe

Is there any way to extract the entity's information(id, class, etc) that is intersected with a raycaster?
I tried to find the information from evt.detail.el but no success.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('collider-check', {

init: function () {
  this.el.addEventListener('raycaster-intersected', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt.detail.el);
  });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the code above logs the *raycasting* entity, rather than the *raycasted* entity, so it is logging the cursor.

Using the code above, you can access the data you need by logging `evt.detail.intersection.object.el`. So you could do something like the following to access `id` and `class`, respectively:

```
console.log(evt.detail.intersection.object.el.id);
console.log(evt.detail.intersection.object.el.className);
```

Here is a demo of the code in action: https://codepen.io/dansinni/pen/bjjbWv

If you haven't bound `this` to the handler, and only need basic attribute data, you should also be able to do the following, but YMMV:

```
console.log(this.id);
console.log(this.className);
```

You should also be able to use a component with the cursor instead, and rely on the `raycaster-intersection` event. Note the difference in the docs: https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/raycaster.html#events